# Why are VFSMs not more commonly used?

Tags: finite-automata, reference-request

For a job several years ago I worked with a team using technologies built around Virtual Finite State Machine models for system fault analysis and remediation. Since then, I've found it to be a generally useful approach for making control decisions in instances when control logic gets complicated and/or needs to be factored out of the rest of the software.

However, besides the initial set of publications that came out in the 90s to early 2000s (with some aborted attempts at commercialization), it seems like this topic has become completely dormant, and I've been scratching my head why.  I've found it to be a very powerful method for modeling problems with an extremely compact implementation (I can write a VFSM execution platform in less than 100 lines of Python code) - are there better methods that I'm completely unaware of? Outside of one team I worked with several years ago, none of my other colleagues are familiar with the model or technique.

The [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_finite-state_machine) gives an overview of what VFSMs are, and the publications that define the execution model.